# React.js, how to bind `this` outside of component

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs

I have a mix of backbone and react. I'm trying to use `this` (or that, self, whatever) to access the backbone view methods (in `HomeView`), within the  `changeSeasons` method. But because `changeSeasons` is being called within the `HomeMainComp` component, `this` is bound to the react component. How can I bind `this` properly so I can access the Backbone view's methods within my `changeSeasons` method?

```
HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
      // init stuff
      this.fetchData();
  },

  fetchData: function(){
      // fetch stuff then runs renderReact...
  },

  renderReact: function(){
    React.render(
      <HomeMainComp
        changeSeasons={this.changeSeasons}
        probablePitchers={this.probablePitchers.toJSON()} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
      );
  },

  changeSeasons: function(seasons){
      console.log(this); // shows the HomeMainComp...,
      this.pitcherStats.setSeasons(seasons); // so this don't work
      this.fetchData(); // this don't work either
  },

    ...

})
```

EDIT: With some advice below I'm able to get the HomeView as my `this`, by binding (null, this) to changeSeasons, but then I need to pass in `this` in my changeSeasons method with another binding?  I'm a little confused what's going on, and in this case, I no longer can access the incoming variable `seasons`.

```
  renderReact: function(){

    React.render(
      <HomeMainComp
        changeSeasons={this.changeSeasons.bind(null, this)}
        probablePitchers={this.probablePitchers.toJSON()} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
            );
     },

  changeSeasons: function(_this){
    console.log('this: ', _this) ## this gives me the HomeView object
    console.log('Season change: ', seasons); ## but now I'm having trouble accessing my incoming seasons variable, which is empty because _this is taking the space.
      _this.pitcherStats.setSeasons(seasons);
      _this.fetchData();
  }.bind(this),
```

Comment: There's always `_.bindAll(this, 'changeSeasons')` in `initialize` or maybe `this.changeSeasons.bind(this)` instead of just `this.changeSeasons`. Not sure what would make the most sense with React though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could bind `changeSeasons` when you render your component:

```javascript
  renderReact: function(){
    React.render(
      <HomeMainComp
        changeSeasons={this.changeSeasons.bind(this)}
        probablePitchers={this.probablePitchers.toJSON()} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
      );
  },
```

This creates a new function every time `renderReact` is called. While probably not a big deal, if you want to minimize function creation/GC, you can bind it earlier:

```javascript
  initialize: function(){
      // init stuff
      this.changeSeasons = this.changeSeasons.bind(this);
      this.fetchData();
  },

  // ...

  renderReact: function(){
    React.render(
      <HomeMainComp
        changeSeasons={this.changeSeasons}
        probablePitchers={this.probablePitchers.toJSON()} />,
        document.getElementById('app')
      );
  },
```

As mu is too short mentioned, Underscore provides a convenience function to bind one or more methods to an object:

```javascript
  initialize: function(){
      // init stuff
      _.bindAll(this, "changeSeasons");
      this.fetchData();
  },
```

Comment: I'm heading in the right direction, but I'm a little confused what's going on. I've updated my question with my progress.

Comment: @Ben `this.changeSeasons.bind(null, this)` is incorrect, you should use `this.changeSeasons.bind(this)`. Then the parameter issue goes away.

Comment: thanks @BinaryMuse I thought I did that and it wasn't working, must have been something else I had causing an issue.